# Ktlint-gradle - create/override lint rules

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-14, editorconfig, ktlint

I am using the [Ktlint-gradle library](https://github.com/JLLeitschuh/ktlint-gradle) in my Android project.

I have recently upgraded to Gradle version `8.2.0` and ktlint version `12.0.3`.

Post upgrade, some of the linting rules have changed and I'd like to override them or disable them. But I am unsure what rules need to be added to the `.editorconfig` file.

**First**
I want to allow inline comments.

e.g.

```
data class Something(
  val someValue: String // comment about someValue
)
```

Ktlint error: A comment in a 'value_argument_list' is only allowed when placed on a separate line (cannot be auto-corrected)

**Second**
I want to allow variables to start with an underscore `_`.

e.g.

```
val _binding = ViewBinding? = null
```

Ktlint error: Property name should start with a lowercase letter and use camel case (cannot be auto-corrected)

---

Could you please assist in providing the rules or settings needed to override these?

Comment: have you made an issue for this on the github ?

Comment: @a_local_nobody I have not, as it could be my lack of understanding rather than an issue?

Comment: entirely possible, i'm only suggesting it because you might get a response there a lot faster, there are certain types of questions which don't really get answers quickly on SO, just feels like this is one of those cases :)